# Android Notification Sound Limit

Tags: android, android-notifications

I have a problem for notification with sound duration.

I send a location notification with sound. My notification sound duration is 5 minutes, but Android not playing 5 minutes. Why? What is the duration limit? Or I can remove sound duration limit?

thanks, have a good day.

Comment: sorry, not possible (AFAIK)

Comment: You can't remove duration limit , but you can use MediaPlayer instead of notification soud player

Comment: This is not possible. If you really want to do that play music in background for that you have to use the background service.

Comment: Its not possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no way to only cancel the sound. Alternatively,control the volume like this:

Control the volume:

```
setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_NOTIFICATION);
```

For mute the Notification sound:

```
final AudioManager am = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
am.setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_NOTIFICATION, true or false);
```